# How to parse a javascript array string into C# representation?

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing

after a web request I receive a line with a javascript array.
Here I have an example:

```
data_161230 = [
    [
        'Imóvel Residencial', 
        'Residencial', 
        'Jurídica/Física', 
        'Por Dia Fixo', 
        'Semestral', 
        '&nbsp;', 
        'Sim', 
        d.c_161230.gridButton('arguments = [];openForm({sys: \'OF2\', form: \'8462\', width: 800, height: 515, centralized: true, posX: 199, posY: 206, newWindow: true, toolbar: false, status: true, menubar: false, scrollbars: false, resizable: false, location: false, mode: -1, modal: false, filter: processFilter(\'A.ID=161558@long\'), target: \'WebrunWindowOF28462\'});; ', 158853, null, {enabled: true, readonly: false, hint: ''}), 
        '&nbsp;'
    ],
    [
        'Imóvel Rural', 
        'Rural', 
        'Jurídica', 
        'Por Data de Vencimento', 
        'Semestral', 
        'Semestral', 
        'Não', 
        d.c_161230.gridButton('arguments = [];openForm({sys: \'OF2\', form: \'8462\', width: 800, height: 515, centralized: true, posX: 199, posY: 206, newWindow: true, toolbar: false, status: true, menubar: false, scrollbars: false, resizable: false, location: false, mode: -1, modal: false, filter: processFilter(\'A.ID=161559@long\'), target: \'WebrunWindowOF28462\'});; ', 158853, null, {enabled: true, readonly: false, hint: ''}), 
        '&nbsp;'
    ]
];
```

I separated in different lines for better comprehension, but I receive this in a single line.

This code have 2 particularities:

- Look that one of the lines have javascript code. I do not need to execute anything, but I need to save this line.
- The javascript var name **data_161230** can be anything and is always different.

How can I extract the javascript array from this code and parse into a C# Array, or List, etc?

Comment: Why do you need to parse it into an array at all? What will you *do* with the data? If all you need to do is store it and regurgitate it on command, you can do that without any parsing. If you want to process it in some way, the way you want to process it will dictate your parsing, which could be as simple as matching outer brackets or as complicated as pre-processing it to JSON (and/or parsing HTML entities like `&nbsp;` into characters).

Comment: Hi @Jeroen. I need to store all this data in different database fields. If I get all this fields separated, the rest is easy. Spliting fields by comma or apostrophe its not effective because of the line with javascript code, than, maybe, i'm trying to find an easier way to parse this.

Comment: Parsing arbitrary JavaScript code is really unnecessarily hard (I mean, without pulling in a fully featured interpreter); if possible, consider (ab)-using simple shortcuts like the fact that the output has line breaks and line #8 in any element is a line of code that should be stored as-is, that sort of thing. If there are no line breaks in the original, God have mercy on your soul. Of course, a better solution would be to make your web request give back JSON rather than raw JS (possibly as an additional option), but I'm presuming you can't do that.

Comment: Do you need to parse this into two separate arrays?

Comment: I broke the code in lines for better understanding, but I receive all in a single line. I do not have control over this response, its from a 3rd part tool.

Comment: Hi @TamásSzabó, yes, my first idea was to parse into two separate arrays, but I'm open for new ideas.

Comment: Well I was thinking you could parse them with regex, since every value is between `'`-s, but you have a lot of special characters, which makes it tricky. You might be better off writing a state machine which first looks for a `[`, then another `[`, then a `'`, then  `',` etc. There also might be some package out there that parses javascript... Good luck anyhow

Comment: If you get it all as one line, I suggest not trying to be clever and use a full JavaScript parser like [jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) to parse this. The alternative is to write your own using some brittle mix of regexes that may fail when the site next changes its format. A full parser (which will essentially execute code) may require you to predefine objects like `d` to capture calls (possibly by hooking syntax error events) so it's still not trivial, but still less work than rolling it all yourself.